# Content-encoding in the Header of index page of Apache 2.4

Tags: apache, gzip, content-encoding

I have Apache 2.4.37 without Nginx and with PHP 7.2.24.
When I download header of my site:

```
$ curl -I  -H  "Accept-Encoding: gzip" https://mysite/
HTTP/2 200
server: Apache/2.4.37 (centos) OpenSSL/1.1.1k
x-powered-by: PHP/7.2.24
expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
pragma: no-cache
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

I can't see Content Encoding gzip in the Header, but if I download index page of my site via:
curl -o index.html  -H  "Accept-Encoding: gzip" https://mysite/
index.html is a gzip archive.

When I download header of my site CSS page(https://mysite/file.css):

```
$ curl -I  -H  "Accept-Encoding: gzip" https://mysite/
HTTP/2 200
server: Apache/2.4.37 (centos) OpenSSL/1.1.1k
accept-ranges: bytes
vary: Accept-Encoding
content-encoding: gzip
cache-control: max-age=31536050
content-length: 5135
content-type: text/css
```

So, where is "content-encoding: gzip" in the Header of  php page  of my site?

I tried to add header('Content-Encoding: gzip'); in the Php code of index.php, but Browser said that invalid Encoding.
Thanks.